# How to thread-safe archive a set of custom objects?

Tags: swift, multithreading, collections, thread-safety, archiving

I have instances of type `Set<CostumObject>` that I want to archive using a `NSKeyedArchiver`.

Assume `customObject1: CostumObject` and `customObject2: CostumObject` are instantiated somewhere.

If I use the following statements:

```
let setOfCostomObjects: Set<CostumObject> = [customObject1, customObject2]
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: setOfCostomObjects)
```

`NSKeyedArchiver` archives sequentially both custom objects where their properties are archived recursively.

This is not thread-safe, since another thread can mutate both custom objects and their properties during archiving.

I think I can thread-safe archive each property of the custom object, so that concurrent gets are allowed but only a single set, by using a concurrent queue with a barrier for set like:

```
private let concurrentPropertyAccessQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "concurrentPropertyAccessQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
…
private var safeProperty = CostumProperty.init()
public private(set) var property: CostumProperty {
  get {
    var result = CostumProperty.init()
    concurrentPropertyAccessQueue.sync { result = safeProperty } // sync, because result is returned
    return result
  } // get
  set { concurrentPropertyAccessQueue.async(flags: .barrier) { safeProperty = newValue } // executes locked after all gets
  } // set
}  
…
public func threadSafeArchiveOfProperty() -> Data {
    var data = Data.init()
    concurrentPropertyAccessQueue.sync {  // sync, because result is returned
      data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.safeProperty) 
    }
    return data
}
```

I think I can also thread-safe archive the whole custom object in a similar way:

```
private let concurrentObjectAccessQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "concurrentObjectAccessQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
…
public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    concurrentObjectAccessQueue.async(execute: {
        aCoder.encode(self.property forKey: "property")
        …
    })
}
```

The problem still is, how to  thread-safe archive the set of custom objects.
This would require that write accesses to the elements of the set are locked out during archiving.

One way to do so is probably to define a global concurrent queue:

```
public let globalConcurrentAccessQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "globalConcurrentAccessQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
```

To lock the set and all its elements during archiving, one could probably write an extension to the `Set` type that defines a `func threadSafeArchiveOfSet()` as above.
This function would then override the Set’s `encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)`, so that the `globalConcurrentAccessQueue` is locked.

Is this the right way to go?
I think this is a standard problem that should have a standard solution.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your quick replies. I have to understand them, and will come back.

Comment: @Rob Regarding property-level synchronization: You are completely right: To keep the object as whole consistent, mutating itself or any property of it must be synchronized at the object level, and property-level synchronization is obsolete. Regarding async encoding: You are right again: The caller, NSKeyedArchiver, probably assumes that encoding is a sequential process, because all individual archiving results will be combined to one final data object.

Comment: @Rob Regarding the simplification of the sync pattern: Interesting! I did not know this. Your suggestion works, but I cannot find it in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1452870-sync). Shouldn’t sync have a return value?

Comment: @Rob Thanks again for your comments. Maybe you can formulate an answer so that I can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, property-level synchronization is simply inadequate. It provides thread-safe access to the individual properties, but it does not ensure thread-safe access to the broader object where there might be interdependencies between different properties. The prototypical example is a `Person` object with first and last name properties. Synchronization changes to the first and last name separately can still end up with the object being captured in an internally inconsistent state. You often need to synchronize the object at a higher level, and if you do that, it renders the property-level synchronization redundent.

A few unrelated observations:

1. The `encode` method must perform its task synchronously, not asychronously. The caller assumes the encoding is complete by the time it returns. I can guess why you may have made it asynchronous (e.g. it isn't explicitly returning anything, after all), but the question isn't whether anything is returned, but rather more broadly whether there are any side-effects outside of the the synchronized object. In this case there are (you're updating the `NSCoder` object), so you must use `sync` in `encode`.
2. A couple of times you employ a pattern of initializing a variable, calling `sync` to modify that local variable, and then returning that value. E.g.

   ```
   func threadSafeArchiveOfProperty() -> Data {
       var data = Data.init()
       concurrentPropertyAccessQueue.sync {  // sync, because result is returned
           data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.safeProperty) 
       }
       return data
   }
   ```

   But `sync` offers a nice way to simplify this, namely if the closure returns a value, `sync` will return it, too. And if the closure has only one line, you don't even need explicit `return` in the closure:

   ```
   func threadSafeArchiveOfProperty() -> Data {
       return concurrentPropertyAccessQueue.sync {  // sync, because result is returned
           NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.safeProperty) 
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Basem Emara described [here](http://basememara.com/creating-thread-safe-arrays-in-swift/) a solution for thread-safe arrays that can be applied also to sets:

He declared a `SynchronizedArray` to mimic a regular array. In it contains a private concurrent queue and array, and exposed several of the array’s properties and methods.
Immutable accesses are done synchronously and concurrently, while mutable accesses are done asynchronously with a barrier, i.e. after all other blocks in the queue terminated.